# web.config needs to set to South Africa's regional and currency

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I need to set my web.config file to South Africa's regional and currency, I have textboxs that I have converted to double for a calculation and it works on my local pc but the server is catching the error " input is in a incorrect format. " and apparently the hosting server cannot change their regional settings. Can anyone help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

To set your culture settings add system.web node that code

```
<globalization culture="af-ZA" uiCulture="af-ZA" />
```

Full web.config file

```
<configuration>
        <system.web>
          <globalization culture="af-ZA" uiCulture="af-ZA" />
          <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
          <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I dont think I understand you fully ?